# Cannot use display:inline with SVG

Tags: html, sass

I'm trying to align an SVG image next to the logo text. However, it won't work with `display: inline`.

HTML

```
<div id="logo">
    <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="ArtPass">
    <p>ArtPass</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#logo {
    color: $white;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5 rem;
    float: left;
    margin:0;
    display:inline;
    img {
        display:inline;
    }
}
```

Comment: add the SVG inside the `p`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between display inline and block on svg elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41437423/difference-between-display-inline-and-block-on-svg-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the paragraph's `display` style. Because, the `p` element has `display:block` style by default.

```css
#logo>p { display: inline-block }
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30/4B89DA/" alt="">
  <p>ArtPass</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According the SVG specification the value of `display: none` indicates that the given element and its children shall not be rendered directly (i.e., those elements are not present in the rendering tree), so any value different than `none` or `inherit` shows that the given element will be rendered by the SVG user agent.